# AngularJS show default html in p tag first but change with input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a `p` tag and an text `input`. I want to show default html (eg. *[[enter text]]*) in the p tag at first (when the page load) but it will be modified when user write some text in the input box. Input tag will have a placeholder (eg. *please enter here*), no default value. I have tried to use `ng-model` in input tag but it also made the value of input equal to the model which I don not want. At page load input tag value will be different than p tag.

**Update**: solved by this way
https://jsfiddle.net/acmnosyf

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make a example for you problem [here](http://jsbin.com/qigugufonu/1/edit?html,js,output).

I set the model for the `p` tag to a different model for the `input`.

```
<p>{{text}}</p>
<input ng-model="inputText" ng-change="changed(inputText)" type="text">
```

So when the input changes the `changed` function is called. In your controller you just have to implement the `changed` function like this

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  var text = "myText";
  $scope.text = text;

  $scope.changed = function(input) {
    $scope.text = input;

    // Resset text to default value
    if (input === "") {
      $scope.text = text;
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit**
Like one of the comments say, one of the most elegant ways to set `p` is

```
<p>{{text ? text : "My text" }}</p>
<input ng-model="text" type="text">
```

Comment: Or with jQuery on key up call method where `$scope.variable` is updated for `p` tag's model.

Comment: Yeah that's right but using jQuery in a controller is not the angular way to do such tasks. Another way is to right a directive which handles the things the controller does, but I think that's the easiest way to achieve the things he wants.

Comment: Yes that right. i was just showing alternative way.

Comment: Also we can do: `<p>
{{Caption ? Caption : 'My text'}}
</p>`